# Bower Install Error EPERM rename sb-admin theme

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install [sb-admin](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/) theme on my local machine and getting below error.

tried clear cache of bower & npm, reinstalled bower nothing worked.

Error:

> bower json3#~3.3.1                            EPERM EPERM, rename
>   'C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Local\bower\cache\packages\82636d37515077f172c7d039afaa3315\3.3.2'
>
> Stack trace: Error: EPERM, rename
>   'C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Local\bower\cache\packages\82636d37515077f172c7d039afaa3315\3.3.2'
>       at Error (native)
>
> Console trace: Error
>       at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:82:37)
>       at Logger. (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower:110:22)
>       at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at Logger.emit (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
>       at C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\index.js:45:20
>       at _rejected (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
>       at C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:870:30
>       at Promise.when (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
>       at C:\Users\vi842397\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
>   System info: Bower version: 1.4.1 Node version: 0.12.7 OS: Windows_NT
>   6.3.9600 x64

Bower.json:

```js
{
  "name": "sb-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.2.1",
    "metisMenu": "~1.1.3",
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },

  "resolutions": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/798) on bower's issue tracker that it was resolved when the user was running bower globally. Try to install bower globally and remove it from your local package using:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then try again.

Others also suggested running the command prompt in administrator mode.